# How do I detect two fingers tap on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multi-touch

How do I detect two fingers tap on the iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not targeting 3.2+:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([touches count] == 2) {
        //etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you can target OS 3.2 or above, you can use a [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  It's really easy to use: just configure it and attach it to the view.  When the gesture is performed, it'll fire the action of the gestureRecognizer's target.

Example:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * r = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewWasDoubleTapped:)];
[r setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:r];
[r release];
```

Then you just implement a `- (void) viewWasDoubleTapped:(id)sender` method, and that will get invoked when `[self view]` gets double-tapped.

EDIT

I just realized you might be talking about detecting a single tap with two fingers. If that's the case, the you can do

```
[r setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2]
```

.

The primary advantage of this approach is that you don't have to make a custom view subclass

Answer (score 2):

Set the `multiTouchEnabled` property to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements allow, use UITapGestureRecognizer.  Otherwise, implement the following UIResponder methods in your custom UIView:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Track throughout to see how many touches there were and whether or not they moved more than your tap/drag threshold.  You must implement all four methods.